# Store Views in an array

Tags: ios, uiview, nsmutablearray

I have three buttons and one view controller.  I want to link three buttons to those three
 different views (pages).

I've tried this by making three views and storing it in an mutable array.

```
ViewArray=  [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:15];


 CGRect  viewRect = CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 10);   
 //VIEW1
UIView* view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:viewRect];
view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];


//VIEW2
UIView* view2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:viewRect];
view2.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

I added three buttons programmatically.  After that for the action of each button I used this:

```
//action for each button    
self.view = [ViewArray objectAtIndex:i];//where i={1,2,3} for different functions
```

but I am not getting what I want.

Comment: `i={1,2,3}` huh?  You mean `i={0,1,2}` surely?

Comment: @trojanfoe, probably, and don't call him Shirley.  :-)

Comment: I have added an answer which I think is what you are looking for. Please consider it thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

A better design would be to add all of the views invisibly, then change their opacity 0.0-1.1 to hide and show.  (also, a key mistake in the OP is that the code *replaces* the view controller view with the subviews, instead of adding them)

```
CGRect  viewRect = CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 10);   
//VIEW1
UIView* view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:viewRect];
view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
view1.tag = 1;
view1.alpha = 0.0;
[self.view addSubview:view1];

//VIEW2
UIView* view2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:viewRect];
view2.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
view1.tag = 2;
view1.alpha = 0.0;
[self.view addSubview:view2];
```

Add a property in your vc's interface that keeps track of the visible view:

```
@property(nonatomic, weak) UIView *visibleSubview;
```

Then the button action:

```
UIView *subview = [self.view viewWithTag:i];
//where i={1,2,3} for different functions
// i really needs to be 1,2,3 here, to correspond to the tags

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    subview.alpha = 1.0;
    self.visibleSubview.alpha = 0.0;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    self.visibleSubview = subview;
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not sure exactly what you want. But in general if you want to access any change multiple objects such as a UIView or UILabels, etc... You can just use and NSArray and a for loop to access and make all the changes without any extra code copies like so:

First of all, setup the NSArray with all your objects like so:

```
NSArray *_viewArray = @[view1, view2]; //etc....
```

And also setup an array with the different UIColors like so:

```
NSArray *_colourArray = @[[UIColor redColor], [UIColor greenColor]]; //etc....
```

And then when you want to access them and edit multiple UIViews or what ever objects, you can just use a for loop like so:

```
for (int loop = 0; loop < ([_viewArray count] - 1); loop++) {
    ((UIView*)_viewArray[loop]).backgroundColor = ((UIColor*)_colourArray[loop]);
}
```

I hope this helps you :)

Comment: Honestly this really is the best answer, it is very easy to use and salable too, unlike the other answers. I just tried it out for an array of UILables I have in my view and it works a treat, thanks :)